How can I access a method that has the same name as an enum variant?
This is not a particularly practical question - I just stumbled across this in Rust that I was surprised compiles, and want to understand more what is going on.
It appears that you can make an enum with a tuple variant AND implement a method with the same name (and signature, although that doesn't appear to matter).
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Test{
    Foo,
    Bar(u64)
}

impl Test {
    /// This function won't get called
    pub fn Bar(x: u64) -> Self {
        println!("In function {:?}", x);
        Self::Foo
    } 
}

fn main() {
    let a = Test::Bar(10);
    println!("{:?}", a)
}

Since it does compile it led me to suspect that the method must somehow live in a different "namespace" to the variant as far as the compiler is concerned, which makes me suspect there would be a way to disambiguate the call.  I couldn't find anything in the documentation or by searching though.

The relevant chapter of the Rust Reference's entire content is "Note: This is a placeholder for future expansion.", so it's quite possible that this is a case that simply wasn't thought of. So far, I haven't found any way to call the associated function; even storing Test::Bar in a variable stores the enum constructor, not the function.

I'm not familiar with Rust, but I wonder if this is stylistically correct Rust with regards to naming conventions for methods and enums. Is it normal for Rust method names to start with an uppercase letter?

@Nzall It is not (they usually follow snake_case) but it is possible.

@Nzall correct, I perhaps should have been even stronger about this not being a practical question.  If you find yourself doing this in real code, step away from the keyboard, you've gone wrong.

The method is completely uncallable.
It was apparently callable from 1.0 to 1.33 as <Test>::Bar, then an error from 1.34 to 1.36, and since then, has always used the variant: Enum variants completely shadow inherent associated functions. #48758

wow I never saw such breaking change in Rust... and I never know this case. This show a lot that nobody care about this problem haha

I'm not surprised that nobody cares, given that (1) idiomatic code has snake_case function, and (2) it's always possible to rename either one. I would prefer if there was an error or warning clearly stating that the method cannot be called, though, for clarity.
